# WordPress Timber/Twig Classic Editor not breaking lines

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I've got an issue with line breaks here in WordPress.

I'm using Timber/Twig and Classic Editor plugin.

The WYIWIGS are created with ACF Pro on different post types.

WordPress is outputting paragraphs like this:

`"Some text"`

rather than

`<p>Some text</p>`

Does anyone know a fix? I've been looking into this for a while and I know wpautop has something to do with this.

I'm using the most recent version of WordPress's core.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this issue. The TinyMCE Advanced plugin fixes this.

Comment: This should do the trick: {{ somevariable|wpautop }} - the output is send to the wpautop filter this way.

Comment: if you've ended up here trying this with previews, as soon as you add Timber's `force`, it strips the linebreaks, so they don't exist in the string anymore by the time it gets to `wpautop`